# Why android SQLite can store double value(java 8 bytes) into float column

Tags: java, android, sqlite

```
Create Table:
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + PERSONS_TABLE + " ("
        + PersonsColumns.ID 
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        ...
            + PersonsColumns.HEIGHT + " FLOAT, "
                    + PersonsColumns.CITY + " STRING);");
Write Data:
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
alues.put(PersonsColumns.HEIGHT, 1.7976931348623157E308);
db.insertOrIgnore(values);
```

You can see the value 1.7976931348623157E308 is out of the FLOAT value range(4 bytes) in sqlite. why it can correctly store this value ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQLite is "typeless".You can store any kind of data you want in any column of any table, regardless of the declared datatype of that column

SQLite also allows the datatype to be omitted.

Comment: If so, why we declare the datatype of the column ?

Answer (score 3):

SQLite3, unlike full fledged DBMS/RDBMS like Oracle, MSSQL, etc has plenty of limitations. For one, it does not support a whole lot of Data Types.

As @Ketan Patel suggested, store the value as a *string* and convert the value back in to float when you need to access the data.And I personally follow the same method too considering that using a *string* Data Type saves a lot of hassles.

Refer to this link for more information on supported Data Types: http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html

This is the gist of it:

> 1.0 Storage Classes and Datatypes
>
> Each value stored in an SQLite database (or manipulated by the
>   database engine) has one of the following storage classes:
>
> NULL. The value is a NULL value.
>
> INTEGER. The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.
>
> REAL. The value is a floating point value, stored as an 8-byte IEEE floating point number.
>
> TEXT. The value is a text string, stored using the database encoding (UTF-8, UTF-16BE or UTF-16LE).
>
> BLOB. The value is a blob of data, stored exactly as it was input.

Answer (score 1):

Not all sqls used the fixed semantic that float is 4 bytes and double is 8 bytes. Instead some allow variable precision floats (internally, just 4 and 8 bytes are allowed in terms of storage). In postgresql if no precision is specified then float defaults to double precision.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/datatype.html#DATATYPE-FLOAT

> PostgreSQL also supports **the SQL-standard notations float and float(p)
>   for specifying inexact numeric types**. Here, p specifies the minimum
>   acceptable precision in binary digits. PostgreSQL accepts float(1) to
>   float(24) as selecting the real type, while float(25) to float(53)
>   select double precision. Values of p outside the allowed range draw an
>   error. **float with no precision specified is taken to mean double
>   precision**.

More relevant [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) for sqlite.

> ### 1.0 Storage Classes and Datatypes
>
> - REAL. The value is a floating point value, stored as an 8-byte IEEE floating point number.

Later on in that page it goes on to say that REAL is used whenever REAL, DOUBLE, DOUBLE PRECISION, or FLOAT are specified.

Answer (score 0):

you can try float values to convert in sting and insert and get simple,
some time float values not get more value that time this problem created.